# Dynamically set google script time driven timers and too many timers error in gmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-apps, gs-installable-triggers

I am using google script for gmail to create a script that will mark emails older than 150 days old as about to be deleted. Because the script will time out after x amount of time, I handle as many emails as I can before that amount of time then set a new trigger for the script to continue running where it left off in 2 minutes.

What I am worried about is that after that new trigger is set and runs it still shows up in the 'current apps triggers' even though it was a specific date and time trigger. If this happens often enough over a period, of say a month, will it cause this error:

> 'This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added.'

Or will the expired specific date and time triggers be deleted automatically at some point?

Does anyone know of a best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps script has a limited of 20 triggers per user/script.
To get around this, I would recommend deleting any old triggers whenever the script is run, using the ScriptApp class.  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() can be used to grab an array of the projects triggers.  If you are only using triggers in this scenario, and deleting them everytime the script is run, your code would look something like this :

```
function triggered(e){
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    try{
       ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[0]);
    }catch(e){

    }
    mainLogic()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. What if I want to keep a trigger so that the script runs every day but deletes all of the old one-time call triggers?

Comment: That's a bit more tricky, but I believe it is do-able using the unique id property.
Each trigger has its own unique id.  
What I would do to find it is first create the daily trigger, then write a function to get and Log it's id.  Do this using the ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() function and then the .getUniqueId() function of the trigger object.
Once you have the id, I would implement a method similar to the one I suggested above, but with a for loop if statement checking each triggers unique id, only running if it isn't the one you want to keep.

Comment: @Jonathan Seed . How to delete trigger by name instead of array id ?